# Creating dynamic page using HTML template & PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a static HTML page which I want to make dynamic using PHP to retrieve data from a database, and showing this on the HTML/PHP page.

I will use pagination in order to do this, as the information that I will need to display may change, therefore it's easier and simpler to be done this way.

I have Googled pagination, and am confident in how it works, however the results that need to be displayed on my HTML page will be based off a field in my database named "category ID".

When the user initially submits the data to my database, it will be categorised (for example, Painting and Decorating or Mechanic).

I have then made a different database table with all of the possible categories, and associated an ID to them. (Not sure if this is the right thing to do, please advise if appropriate).

So when a user searches for say "Painting and Decorating" it will be associated with an ID of 1, and my idea is to then filter the database to all listings with an ID of 1, and display on my page.

However, I am having difficulty with filtering the data within the database by category ID. The tutorial I have followed is [here](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination).

Comment: 1) with `PDO` or `mysqli` peformance and security are about the same just not use `mysql`. 2) And `SELECT` query goes the same for both. Just get all data, fetch and show it on the page. 3) This depends on data of that row and how you specificly want to use / show it

Comment: The 3) is called `pagination`. That should give you the direction you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. You use PDO *in order to* perform a select statement; it's a SQL database API for PHP. And yes, I would recommend using PDO. Things I like about it include: 1. it's object-oriented 2. it abstracts away the details of using any particular SQL API (SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.). Keep in mind that using PDO is neither necessary nor sufficient for writing a secure application -- it is the developer's responsibility to ensure that a site is not vulnerable to SQL injection, XSS (cross-site scripting) attacks, and the like. It is certainly possible to write an application using PDO that is vulnerable to both of those.
2. Simple string values like title and description are easy enough -- just interpolate them in your page like any other PHP variable:

   ```
   <div>
     <div class="site-title"><?= htmlspecialchars($row->Title) ?></div>
     <div class="site-description"><?= htmlspecialchars($row->Description) ?></div>
   </div>
   ```

   Note that in this example I remembered to escape the values for HTML properly. Neglecting to do so could not only break the validity and/or layout of your page, but also make your site vulnerable to XSS attacks if those values are user-submitted. You handle Website and Image in essentially the same way -- your task is to interpolate those values into your HTML in such a way that a link to the website and the correct image under the `images/` folder is displayed. Here's how you might do that:

   ```
   <div><a class="site-link" href="<?= htmlspecialchars($row->Website) ?><?= htmlspecialchars($row->Website) ?></a></div>
   <img class="site-image"
     src="images/<?= htmlspecialchars(urlencode($row->Image)) ?>"
     alt="<?= htmlspecialchars($row->Title) ?>">
   ```

   This example will only work if your images are in fact being served from a public `images/` directory relative to the URL of the current page. I also URL-encoded the filepath in order to escape any characters which are not valid in URLs (for example, this converts spaces in the file name to `+` characters; there is also a poorly-named variant called `rawurlencode` which converts spaces to `%20`, which is the actual standard strictly speaking).
3. Yes, that would be the thing to do. You can achieve pagination quite easily with the `offset` and `limit` SQL clauses.

PDO has many options to customize its behavior, and a full example is a little involved, but here's a small example of using a MySQL database:

```
    <?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    // You ***MUST*** sanitize $page here **
    $conn = new \PDO(
      'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database_name;charset=utf8mb4',
      $username, $password);
    $stmt = $conn->query('select Title from websites limit 12 offset ' . (($page - 1) * 12));
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while(($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) !== null): ?>
      <li><?= htmlspecialchars($row->Title) ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I've read a lot of conflicting information so thanks for clearing it up. I will be working on this today and tomorrow, so hopefully it will go well and I will use what you've said!

Comment: Maybe it's because many novice web developers choose PHP, but misinformation seems to spread like a plague when it comes to this language. http://codefury.net/2011/04/why-php-was-a-ghetto/